# PHPExcel getCellCollection is always points to lastsheet in my excel

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel plugin in codeigniter
and my requirement is i have a excel file with multiple sheets

by using below code i am trying to get some data from excel sheets
in looping with getAllSheets,getCellCollection is always pointing to the last only

example my out

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [timing] => Array ( [0] => 10:30 PM [1] => 7:30 AM ) [header] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [D] => 2017-03-27 [E] => 2017-03-28 [F] => 2017-03-29 [G] => 2017-03-30 [H] => 2017-03-31 ) ) [arr_data] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [A] => Damojipurapu Venkata Raghavendra Praveen [B] => Array ( [0] => Railway new colony [1] => 9052932938 ) [C] => 08:50 PM [G] => OFF ) [6] => Array ( [A] => Seerapu Venkata Rao [B] => Array ( [0] => Maharanipeta [1] => 9701964583 ) [C] => 09:00 PM ) [7] => Array ( [A] => Challa Vinod Kumar [B] => Array ( [0] => Chinna Walter [1] => 9963463234 ) [C] => 09:10 PM [D] => 6:00AM [E] => OFF ) [8] => Array ( [A] => Satish Kumar [B] => Array ( [0] => Maruthi Paradise, Opp Vilas Rest,PM palem [1] => 9731347726 ) [C] => 09:20 PM ) [9] => Array ( [A] => Bandi Saketh Reddy [B] => Array ( [0] => Madhurwada [1] => 8501999751 ) [C] => 09:40 PM [H] => OFF ) [10] => Array ( [A] => D Selvaa Murugan [B] => Array ( [0] => Car Shed Madhurwada [1] => 9043287087 ) [C] => 09:50 PM ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [timing] => Array ( [0] => 10:30 PM [1] => 7:30 AM ) [header] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [D] => 2017-03-27 [E] => 2017-03-28 [F] => 2017-03-29 [G] => 2017-03-30 [H] => 2017-03-31 ) ) [arr_data] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [A] => Damojipurapu Venkata Raghavendra Praveen [B] => Array ( [0] => Railway new colony [1] => 9052932938 ) [C] => 08:50 PM [G] => OFF ) [6] => Array ( [A] => Seerapu Venkata Rao [B] => Array ( [0] => Maharanipeta [1] => 9701964583 ) [C] => 09:00 PM ) [7] => Array ( [A] => Challa Vinod Kumar [B] => Array ( [0] => Chinna Walter [1] => 9963463234 ) [C] => 09:10 PM [D] => 6:00AM [E] => OFF ) [8] => Array ( [A] => Satish Kumar [B] => Array ( [0] => Maruthi Paradise, Opp Vilas Rest,PM palem [1] => 9731347726 ) [C] => 09:20 PM ) [9] => Array ( [A] => Bandi Saketh Reddy [B] => Array ( [0] => Madhurwada [1] => 8501999751 ) [C] => 09:40 PM [H] => OFF ) [10] => Array ( [A] => D Selvaa Murugan [B] => Array ( [0] => Car Shed Madhurwada [1] => 9043287087 ) [C] => 09:50 PM ) ) ) )
```

and my code is

```
try {
                $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file["tmp_name"]);
                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file["tmp_name"]);
                $all_data=array();
                foreach ($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
                    //echo $sheet->getTitle()."<br>";
                    $cell_collection = $sheet->getCellCollection();
                    //print_r($cell_collection);
                    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
                        $c=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell);
                        $column = $c->getColumn();
                        $row = $c->getRow();
                        $data_value = $c->getValue();
                        if(strstr($data_value,'=')==true)
                        {
                            $data_value = $c->getOldCalculatedValue();
                        }
                        if ($row == 3) {
                            if(count($data_value)>0){
                                $a = explode("Shift: ",$data_value);
                                $data["timing"] =array_map('trim',explode("-",$a[1]));
                            }
                        }else if ($row == 4){
                            if($column!='A'&&$column!='B'&&$column!='C'){
                                if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($c)) {
                                    $data_value = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($c->getValue())->format('Y-m-d');
                                }
                                if(count($data_value)>0)
                                    $data["header"][$row][$column] = $data_value;
                            }

                        }else if ($row > 4){
                            if($column=='B'){
                                if(count($data_value)>0)
                                $data_value=array_map('trim',explode("/",$data_value));
                            }
                            if($column=='C'){
                                if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($c)) {
                                    $data_value = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($c->getValue())->format('h:i A');
                                }
                            }
                            if(count($data_value)>0)
                            $data["arr_data"][$row][$column] = $data_value;
                        }
                    }
                    array_push($all_data, $data);
                    $data=array();

                }
                //echo "<pre>";
                print_r($all_data);
                exit;
            }catch (Exception $ex) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you,
I found Solution

Actually i need to get data $sheet not with $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(),
by doing this it causes to always read data from the sheet where we last saved that excel file,
I just change this line

```
$c=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell);
```

to

```
$c=$sheet->getCell($cell);
```

then its fixed for me

Once agian thanks to all

Comment: Yes, if you want to get data for a specific sheet, then you have to tell PHPExcel which sheet to get data from, or which sheet to set as the active sheet